# SoundCloud API error 'Refused to execute… as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type'

Tags: jsonp, mime-types, soundcloud, x-content-type-options

My site here here has suddenly stopped playing music tracks (I set these up via SoundCloud's API):

https://www.instrumentalbackgroundmusic.com/royalty-free-music/blueprint/

I'm a bit out of my depth here as my site was working fine, but now I've got *Refused to execute [Soundcloud API URL with JSONP callback] as script because “X-Content-Type: nosniff” was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type'* errors that I have no idea how to fix.

I've looked around online, but some of the solutions like setting up a proxy server aren't available to me, so I'm wondering if there's a fix I can implement on the server using HTACCESS or something?

Can anyone help guide me as to how I might fix the issue?

Comment: CORS is their ability to exert control over who uses their services.  Without the use of a proxy, you cannot give yourself access to their resources; *they* have to give *you* access.  This is usually done via an authentication or API token.  I do not know the specifics of their API.  Can you share your code with us?

Comment: The cause: `https://api.soundcloud.com/` is serving `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/NNN.json?callback=` URLs with a 'Content-Type: application/json' response header. It shouldn’t be, because the contents aren’t JSON—they’re instead executable JSONP IIFE JavaScript. And your browser’s refusing to execute it because it’s also served with a 'X-Content-Type: nosniff' header. The fix is: `https://api.soundcloud.com/` should instead be serving those with a 'Content-Type: text/javascript' header. There’s otherwise no way to fix this on your side in your frontend code. Soundcloud needs to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, it seems to be something that is affecting not only SoundCloud but also the other third-party services on my site. Is this something that is affecting anyone else or just me?